# Web RTC wont allow chrome to use my camera

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am trying to study web RTC. This is example where I just want to show my camera video.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web RTC</title>
</head>
<body>
<video autoplay></video>
<script type="text/javascript">

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                                navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    var video = document.querySelector('video');

    var hdConstraints = {
        video : {
            mandatory: {
                minWidth: 1280,
                minHeight: 720
            }
        }
    };

    var errorCallback = function(e) {
        console.log('Rejected!', e);
    };

    var successCallback = function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia(hdConstraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
    }
    else {
        console.log('sh');
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem is that chrome wont let my camera start. I was clicking on camera icon and I told chrome that he should ask me next time for permission...  if anyone is thinking in that direction, that is not the case. In Firefox this works just fine. That first console log is throwing an error and Google did not helped me with it. You can try i your self. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Chrome has security restrictions.  Are you executing this page using a webserver over http or https?

Comment: Do you see your camera listed in the available cameras, on the camera symbol at the address top bar?

Comment: Camera was listed as available device. mtbikemike had it. It was https issue. Thank you. For further study, if anyone cares, look at EasyRTC node.js project. It helped me so far.